# Deploy Jhipster APP to Wildfly

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, wildfly, jhipster

I'm trying to deploy a JHipster app to wildfly 12 but I'm getting the following error

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loggingConfiguration' defined in VFS resource

What do I need to do to do this deploy?

Comment: Why not using your JHipster app as it is intended: as a standalone executable war? Deploying it in a jee server is always difficult whatever the server is, just search in stackoverflow and you'll understand.

Comment: I would prefer to use as a standalone exe war.. But I'm looking for the pros and cons to using the standalone application in the client environment... I need something fully free and open-source to deploy this app

Comment: What's the difference between embedding Undertow in executable war as it is done by default in JHipster and what you are trying to do which is deploying into Wildfly which also embeds Undertow? No difference in terms of open source except more code and additional complexity for the Wildfly option

Comment: I agree, it adds more complexity... But in terms of performance, security, management when using embedded?

Comment: It starts faster (only what you need is started), no reason why it should perform worse. Good luck with Wildfly.

Comment: I see.. I as able to deploy the same war to Tomcat 9! But thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In LoggingConfiguration bean for Logtash config, jHipster try to cast ILoggerFactory instance to LoggerContext (ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext) at runtime.

```
private LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
```

You can skip this by customizing it in LoggingConfiguration class when deploy a JHipster app to Wildfly.

Reference (line 35): https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/config/LoggingConfiguration.java